# Changing values of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration, slice

I have a list of hashes such as:

```
f71bc81a7e7d649f0d279b5861972eae  ./.bash_history
22bfb8c1dd94b5f3813a2b25da67463f  ./.bash_logout
1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6  ./.bashrc
f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97  ./.profile
595dbcceb1b5921f7fad73ad17ec1fe4  ./.python_history
a23829cea89e42d79df01428e550191a  ./.viminfo
```

And I need to modify all the second "columns" (./.bash_history) to become a unique name. Like below:

```
    f71bc81a7e7d649f0d279b5861972eae  App1
    22bfb8c1dd94b5f3813a2b25da67463f  App1
    1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6  App1
    f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97  App1
```

I can't come up with a way of doing this in simple terms. (Bare in mind the whitespaces between the hash and the name). I tried slicing, iterating through it and changing values but I don't get the result I want.

What I tried:

```
import re
f = open("md5sum.txt","r")
read = f.read()
ar =  re.sub(r"\s+", "", read)
splitting = ar.split('.')
print(splitting[1])
for x in range(len(splitting)):
    if splitting[x] % 2 != 0:
        print("App1")
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: "I can't come up with a way of doing this in simple terms" What have you tried in "not so simple terms"? And what is the result that you got? Also, do you have some performance requirements?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @BudaGavril I tried converting the list to pandas dataframe and trying to modify the column however I have not succeed due to the whitespacing in between. I tried delimiters and and regex but got no luck. I don't have any performance requirements.

Comment: [mcve] of what you tried? What you posted here is not even a list but just some data ... hard to say whats where with that

Comment: We'll need more context before we can give you a solution to your problem. What structure is your data in? You say it's a list, but it looks like it may be a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @JordanSinger Structure is a txt file as it was extracted from command "sudo find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; > md5sum.txt"

Comment: `
import re
f = open("md5sum.txt","r")
read = f.read()
ar =  re.sub(r"\s+", "", read)
splitting = ar.split('.')
print(splitting[1])
for x in range(len(splitting)):
    if splitting[x] % 2 != 0:
        print("App1")`

Comment: Done @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your goal is exactly, but based on what I assume you want, I believe this code will suffice.

```
replaced_value = 'App1'

with open('md5sum.txt') as fin:
  with open('md5sum_modified.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
      values = line.split()
      values[1] = replaced_value
      new_line = ' '.join(values)
      fout.write(new_line + '\n')
```

Comment: you can chain open() in one `with` line to have less indendation happening if they can start/end at the same time and you most probably have empty lines afterwards due to double \n\n...best to check your code as [mcve] - f.e. http://pyfiddle.io

Answer (score 0):

**Create file**:

```
t = """f71bc81a7e7d649f0d279b5861972eae  ./.bash_history
22bfb8c1dd94b5f3813a2b25da67463f  ./.bash_logout
1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6  ./.bashrc
f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97  ./.profile
595dbcceb1b5921f7fad73ad17ec1fe4  ./.python_history
a23829cea89e42d79df01428e550191a  ./.viminfo"""

fn = "md5sum.txt"
with open(fn,"w")as f:f.write(t)
```

**Read and process file line by line**:

```
data = []
with open(fn) as f, open("changed.txt","w") as w:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            # split at spaces
            h, _ = line.strip().split()
            # ignore _ - simply give it a new one
            w.write(f"{h} all_the_same_name\n")

with open("changed.txt") as f: 
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
f71bc81a7e7d649f0d279b5861972eae all_the_same_name
22bfb8c1dd94b5f3813a2b25da67463f all_the_same_name
1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6 all_the_same_name
f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97 all_the_same_name
595dbcceb1b5921f7fad73ad17ec1fe4 all_the_same_name
a23829cea89e42d79df01428e550191a all_the_same_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `str.replace()`, as follows:

```
f = open(r"md5sum.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
new_read = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace(line.split(' ')[2], 'Appl')
    new_read.append(line)
```

then this would be the output of `new_read` list:

```
['f71bc81a7e7d649f0d279b5861972eae  Appl', '22bfb8c1dd94b5f3813a2b25da67463f  Appl', '1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6  Appl', 'f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97  Appl', '595dbcceb1b5921f7fad73ad17ec1fe4  Appl', 'a23829cea89e42d79df01428e550191a  Appl']
```